# We used to live there five years ago - is it correct?

Tags: past-tense, used-to

my question is actually in the title. I'm confused by the past time expression "ago"+ used to, although I don't see a proper explanation of whether it's possible or not. I usually see used to + "when I was a child", "when we lived there" and so on, but not + expressions with a specific time.

What do you think, is it proper usage or not allowed/not common. Probably, you have you read something on this matter. I'd appreciate a reference

Comment: As writing advice (which is off-topic) this sentence is fine if you want to emphasise the amount of time, but isn't usual otherwise. If you want to emphasise that it's a long time since you lived there, then putting the time on the end is OK, although you might punctuate it "We used to live there ⁠— five years ago."

Answer (score 1):

The usage of "used to + ago" is not common or considered standard English grammar. The correct way to use "used to" is with a reference to a specific time or situation, such as "when I was a child," or "when we lived there." "Ago" is typically used with a specific time in the past, such as "three years ago." Mixing the two expressions, "used to + ago," can result in an awkward or incorrect sentence structure. It is recommended to use them separately to convey the intended meaning clearly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is exactly what I think about it, although I seek for an explanation and proof to be sure. thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

My colleague has just shared this screenshot with me on another chat where I posted the same question. Problem solved. Used to + ago is impossible. It's Swan "Practical English Usage". The author says that the construction Used to is not used simply to say what happened at a particular past time. The example of an incorrect sentence: I used to work very hard last month - it's inappropriate.

[image]

Comment: The screen shot doesn't actually answer your question. (1) We used to live there. (2) We used to live there 5 years ago. Your screen shot is making the point that in both sentences "used to" implies you no longer live there. If sentence (2) is wrong, it's wrong for other reasons. (Mainly, as noted above, that "ago" references a point in time, and "lived" best matches that meaning.)

Comment: Screenshots are not accessible to web browsers for the blind.  Please correct the post.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Peter Kirkpatrick I'm happy with the continuous (but probably now ended) 'Five years ago, we were living in Skipton.' 'Ago' is a strange fish: 'She died five years ago' is certainly idiomatic. Perhaps the continuous usage packages a time interval into a notional point ... sometimes.